# JVM for WEPOS

Tags: java, windows, embedded, jvm

I'm looking into running a j2se(1.5) application on the WEPOS(Windows Embedded for Point of Service) platform.  I noticed that Sun offeres a java runtime for Windows XP embedded (Java SE for Embedded 5.0).  I'm wondering if

1. Can I use the standard Sun Hotspot on the WEPOS platforms?
2. Will Java SE for Embedded 5.0 also run on WEPOS?  (If so, SE for Embedded will make better use of the limited resources)

thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wepos Product Overview](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/4/D/14DD5554-0C2A-4B89-ACDC-CBB94F65EBE4/WEPOS%20Product%20Overview%20White%20Paper.pdf) you should be able to install J2SE (1.5) on it:

"The Windows Embedded for Point of Service operating system is fully compatible with technology built for Windows XP Professional, including existing Windows XP drivers. WEPOS provides binary compatibility with Windows XP Professional and Microsoft Win32® operating system APIs, which eases application development and migration and provides support for **Java Virtual Machines**."